# ASP.NET Web API post Byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, microsoft-azure

Estou criando um *Web API* e meu model tem uma propriedade `byte[]`, porém sempre que tento realizar um `Post` meu model chega null, tirando a propriedade `byte[]` ele chega normalmente o model.

```
[Table("Pessoas")]
public class Pessoa : ITableData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

a propriedade `byte[] Version` é uma implementação da `ITableData`.

```
// POST: api/Pessoas
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostPessoa([FromBody] Pessoa pessoa)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _context.Pessoas.Add(pessoa);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetPessoa", new { id = pessoa.Id }, pessoa);
}
```

A implementação do `ITableData` faz parte de uma futura tentativa de trabalhar com o `Sdk` do `Azure` para trabalhar com a sincronização de dados em um aplicativo `mobile`.

Mas mesmo assim fica a questão, como dar um `Post` em um model com uma propriedade do tipo `byte[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Mas mesmo assim fica a questão, como dar um `Post` em um model com uma propriedade do tipo `byte[]`?

Eu queria entender o porquê de você ter um `Timestamp` em cliente, sendo que não é nem uma propriedade que deveria ficar visível para o usuário.

De qualquer forma, para mandar um `byte[]` para uma API, você precisa usar um *Media Formatter* que suporte `byte[]`, como BSON (Binary JSON):

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.Add(new BsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    }
}
```

Só que essa informação terá que ser serializada em BSON para ser compreendida corretamente. Para isso, você terá que usar algo que serialize em BSON no cliente, [algo como a `js-bson`](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson).

Comment: Então, o que estou tentando criar é um backend para trabalhar com dados offline em um cliente mobile, agora li melhor a documentação e achei um exemplo do próprio Azure que mostra melhor como montar esse backend.